# Mysql - order a product table based on two column: discounted_price and price

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison, sql-order-by

I have a table with the following columns (I simplified it a little):

- PRODUCT_name
- PRODUCT_code
- PRODUCT_price
- PRODUCT_discounted_price

Now, when I display them, they can be ordered by price. The problem is: how can I take into account both PRODUCT_price and PRODUCT_discounted_price so that if there's PRODUCT_discounted_price it compares by it but if it isn't there it is just ignored?

For example, if I have the following products:

- Name, 1, 12, 10
- Name2, 2, 11, 0
- Name3, 3, 6, 0
- Name4, 4, 25, 9
- Name5, 5, 30, 13

They should be ordered like this:

- Name3, 3, 6, 0
- Name4, 4, 25, 9
- Name, 1, 12, 10
- Name2, 2, 11, 0
- Name5, 5, 30, 13

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select name, code, if(discounted_price=0,price,discounted_price) as real_price 
from product
order by real_price
```

Answer (score 2):

```
order by (case 
          when product_discounted_price = 0 then product_price 
          else product_discounted_price 
          end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make discounted_price column values NULL when they are not used and then order using COALESCE:

```
SELECT COALESCE(PRODUCT_discounted_price, PRODUCT_price) AS order_col FROM products ORDER BY order_col
```

If you do not wish to use NULLs, the same query could be rewritten using IF instead of COALESCE, but it would be a bit more complicated that way.

Comment: -1 COALESCE returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values. Price are not Nulls but zeros.

Comment: That's why I wrote this part:
"You could **make** discounted_price column values **NULL** when they are not used and then order using COALESCE"

Actually, it is more logical to have actual NULL values if a price is not present.